# Matlab random number range

Tags: matlab, random, numbers, range

I am struggling generating a random number within the range of x.

So say x is 4 the range would be -2 to 2 and if it was 6 then -3 to 3.

I know it is

```
rand() * something + somethingelse
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to take out the mean of `rand*x`, that is `x/2`:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
rand(1,numel(x)).*x-x/2

ans =

    0.4172   -0.4283    0.7716    1.0149   -0.5978    0.4069   -2.9690
```

Answer (score 1):

From where you left it is not hard to find the solution:

```
rand() * something + somethingelse
```

From left to right:

`rand()` : From 0 to 1

We want to make the range 4 times as wide, so we do:

`rand()*4` : From 0 to 4

Now the width is correct, we just need to give it the correct location:

`rand()*4-2`: From -2 to 2